# Why can't DNS resolve in this GitLab CI configuration?

Tags: c#, gitlab, rabbitmq, gitlab-ci

I am trying to connect to a RabbitMQ service in my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, but I am getting errors trying to connect to the service.

**Given** this configuration:

```yaml
testing:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - arm64
  needs:
    - "build_linux_arm64"
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1
  services:
    - name: rabbitmq:3.9-alpine
      variables:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: rabbit
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: rabbit
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  script:
  - dotnet test -p:"WarningLevel=0" --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=..\artifacts\{assembly}-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
    - "./**/*test-result.xml"
    reports:
      junit:
      - "./**/*test-result.xml"
```

**And** this is the connection string: `amqp://rabbit:rabbit@rabbitmq-3.9-alpine:5762`

**When** I trigger the pipeline with a commit,

**Then** this is the result:

```csharp
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed) 
---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed 
---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known 
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, ValueStopwatch stopwatch) 
at System.Net.Dns.<>c.<GetHostEntryOrAddressesCoreAsync>b__33_0(Object s, ValueStopwatch stopwatch) 
at System.Net.Dns.<>c__DisplayClass39_0`1.<RunAsync>b__0(Task <p0>, Object <p1>) 
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke() 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
--- End of stack trace from previous location
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `services:` the hostname for the service container will simply be the repository name, without the tag. In this case `rabbitmq` (not `rabbitmq-3.9-alpine`).